# I think him / I think of him

Tags: verbs

In this situation two interviewers are seeing two resumes on which identification pictures of two candidates are printed.

> Who do you want to employ for the position?

Which is the correct answer to the question ?

1. I think him.
2. I am thinking him.
3. I think of him.
4. I am thinking of him.
5. I think he is.
6. I am thinking he is.

Comment: "*I think, him.*" is possible.

Comment: @SovereignSun So, do you mean that 'I think him' is incorrect, and the comma must be added between think and him?

Comment: 1. is possibly the best. I'm not convinced that the comma @SovereignSun suggests is necessary, but comma usage is always fraught; 2. to me, means that the person speaking is hesitant about this choice; 3. has a different meaning from what you are suggesting in the context, as does 4. Not 5 or 6.

Comment: @SIS No. It's correct. The comma adds a short pause *(while one is thinking)*. It's optional though.

Comment: The rest are wrong in fact. "*thinking*" in the continuous isn't okay here, since it doesn't take up much time or effort. "**of**" implies some kind of worriness or interest, or even sounds like you miss him. #3 means that you do it everyday. #5&6 don't agree with the question - "*Whom do want to employ*"<>"*he is*".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the question is, "Who do you want to employ for the position?", then surely the correct answer would be "I think him." No other answers really make sense in this scenario except for 2, however 2 seems overly wordy without adding anything meaningful.

3 and 4 make it sound like you're referring to the candidate in a fashion that would suggest you have a yearning to see him, or miss him, as Sovereign suggested.

5 and 6 simply don't make sense grammatically as you do not reply to this type of question with "I think he is," or "I am thinking he is."

Answer (score 1):

To the question "**Who do you want to employ for the position?**" the answer should contain an object pronoun *(him,her,it,me,us,them,you)* so **#5** and 
**#6** drop out.

The preposition "**of**" implies different things:

- "**[think of sb](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/think-of-sth-sb)**" is a phrasal verb and means "*If you think of something or someone in a particular way, you have that opinion about it, him, or her*" *(definition from Cambridge Dictionary)* [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/think%20of) gives another definition - "*to be concerned about (someone or something) when making decisions about what to do*". And yet another one from Merriam-Webster - "*to form or have an idea about (someone or something)*" However, **#3** and **#4** don't apply under these definitions so we drop them out too.

As for **#2** the continuous tense may imply this:

1. The process is taking up much time or effort, or the speaker is hesitating. "*Is is it difficult for him to choose?*" or "*Is taking him a long time to choose?*" It's not the case in this scenario, and I can't imagine any scenario where this could work.

So this leaves us with the best and only choice - **#1**.